# Using jQuery slider to change Google chart viewWindow

Tags: jquery-ui, slider, google-visualization

I have prepared a simple test case with screenshot, demonstrating my problem and am probably missing a tiny bit, just few lines of code.

I have a diagram representing wins and losses in a web game over the weeks.

I.e. the vertical axis represents the game score and the horizontal axis represents numbers of weeks.

My ajax script returns the data for 52 weeks, but I'd like to add a slider and allow users change the viewed number of weeks to any number between 12 and 52.

[image: screenshot]

Can anybody please advise me, how to modify the [change](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider) function?

```
$("#money_slider").slider({
    min: 12, 
    max: 52,
    change: function(event, ui) { 
        // XXX what to do here with
        // hAxis.viewWindow.min and .max?
    }
});
```

Below is my complete test case, just save it to an .html file and you will be able to try it in a browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    h3,p,div { 
        text-align: center; 
    }

    #slider { 
        width: 700px; 
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto; 
    }
</style>
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
        @import "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css";
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart'],'language':'ru'}]}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

$(function() {
    $('#slider').slider({
        disabled: true,
        range: 'min',
        min: 12,
        max: 52,
        change: function(event, ui) { 
            // XXX what to do here with
            // hAxis.viewWindow.min and .max?
            $("#header").text("debug=" + ui.value);
        }
    });
});

function drawChart() {
        var jsonData = '{"cols":[{"label":"Week number","type":"string"},{"label":"Week leader","type":"number"},{"label":"Your win","type":"number"},{"label":"Your loss","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"2011-33"},{"v":10671},{"v":0},{"v":-3113}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-34"},{"v":7975},{"v":0},{"v":-2113}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-35"},{"v":11009},{"v":0},{"v":-2244}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-36"},{"v":10679},{"v":0},{"v":-689}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-37"},{"v":11197},{"v":305},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-38"},{"v":6762},{"v":419},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-39"},{"v":7823},{"v":0},{"v":-1563}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-40"},{"v":10171},{"v":1152},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-41"},{"v":9903},{"v":0},{"v":-1008}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-42"},{"v":5940},{"v":0},{"v":-1332}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-43"},{"v":7979},{"v":0},{"v":-593}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-44"},{"v":7833},{"v":0},{"v":-653}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-45"},{"v":9691},{"v":0},{"v":-562}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-46"},{"v":8836},{"v":0},{"v":-1686}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-47"},{"v":10358},{"v":0},{"v":-2120}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-48"},{"v":9956},{"v":0},{"v":-1353}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-49"},{"v":8787},{"v":160},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-50"},{"v":9590},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-51"},{"v":8931},{"v":887},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-52"},{"v":8529},{"v":0},{"v":-1434}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-01"},{"v":8680},{"v":0},{"v":-1416}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-02"},{"v":9932},{"v":0},{"v":-169}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-03"},{"v":8334},{"v":0},{"v":-3149}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-04"},{"v":8077},{"v":217},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-05"},{"v":7788},{"v":0},{"v":-3683}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-06"},{"v":10070},{"v":113},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-07"},{"v":8318},{"v":1704},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-08"},{"v":8208},{"v":0},{"v":-104}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-09"},{"v":11561},{"v":272},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-10"},{"v":7797},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-11"},{"v":9893},{"v":0},{"v":-90}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-12"},{"v":9197},{"v":0},{"v":-191}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-13"},{"v":7287},{"v":651},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-14"},{"v":7072},{"v":646},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-15"},{"v":7183},{"v":0},{"v":-907}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-16"},{"v":6021},{"v":0},{"v":-993}]}]}';

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
        var options = {
          width: 700,
          height: 500,
          legend: {position: 'top'},
          areaOpacity: 1.0,
          vAxis: {format: '$#'},
          hAxis: {title: 'Week number', titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue'}, slantedText: true},
          colors: ['CCFFCC', '66CC66', 'FF9999'],
          animation: {duration: 1000, easing: 'out'}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.SteppedAreaChart(document.getElementById('money'));
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
            $('#slider').slider('enable');
        });
        chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h3 id="header">Money</h3>
<div id="money"></div>
<div id="slider"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've read [the Google example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation) (on the bottom), but don't grok it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own solution (has rendering problems with Opera 11.62 though - I've filed [a bug #882](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=882) for that):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    h3,p,div { 
        text-align: center; 
    }

    #slider { 
        width: 700px; 
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto; 
    }
</style>
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
        @import "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css";
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart'],'language':'ru'}]}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.setOnLoadCallback(initChart);

var jsonData = '{"cols":[{"label":"Week number","type":"string"},{"label":"Week leader","type":"number"},{"label":"Your win","type":"number"},{"label":"Your loss","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"2011-33"},{"v":10671},{"v":0},{"v":-3113}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-34"},{"v":7975},{"v":0},{"v":-2113}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-35"},{"v":11009},{"v":0},{"v":-2244}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-36"},{"v":10679},{"v":0},{"v":-689}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-37"},{"v":11197},{"v":305},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-38"},{"v":6762},{"v":419},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-39"},{"v":7823},{"v":0},{"v":-1563}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-40"},{"v":10171},{"v":1152},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-41"},{"v":9903},{"v":0},{"v":-1008}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-42"},{"v":5940},{"v":0},{"v":-1332}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-43"},{"v":7979},{"v":0},{"v":-593}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-44"},{"v":7833},{"v":0},{"v":-653}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-45"},{"v":9691},{"v":0},{"v":-562}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-46"},{"v":8836},{"v":0},{"v":-1686}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-47"},{"v":10358},{"v":0},{"v":-2120}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-48"},{"v":9956},{"v":0},{"v":-1353}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-49"},{"v":8787},{"v":160},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-50"},{"v":9590},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-51"},{"v":8931},{"v":887},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2011-52"},{"v":8529},{"v":0},{"v":-1434}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-01"},{"v":8680},{"v":0},{"v":-1416}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-02"},{"v":9932},{"v":0},{"v":-169}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-03"},{"v":8334},{"v":0},{"v":-3149}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-04"},{"v":8077},{"v":217},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-05"},{"v":7788},{"v":0},{"v":-3683}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-06"},{"v":10070},{"v":113},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-07"},{"v":8318},{"v":1704},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-08"},{"v":8208},{"v":0},{"v":-104}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-09"},{"v":11561},{"v":272},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-10"},{"v":7797},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-11"},{"v":9893},{"v":0},{"v":-90}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-12"},{"v":9197},{"v":0},{"v":-191}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-13"},{"v":7287},{"v":651},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-14"},{"v":7072},{"v":646},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-15"},{"v":7183},{"v":0},{"v":-907}]},{"c":[{"v":"2012-16"},{"v":6021},{"v":0},{"v":-993}]}]}';

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
var chart;
var options = {
    width: 700,
    height: 500,
    legend: {position: 'top'},
    areaOpacity: 1.0,
    vAxis: {format: '$#'},
    hAxis: {title: 'Week number', titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue'}, slantedText: true, viewWindow: {min: 20, max: 35}},
    colors: ['CCFFCC', '66CC66', 'FF9999'],
    animation: {duration: 1000, easing: 'out'}
};

$(function() {
    $('#slider').slider({
        disabled: true,
        range: 'min',
        value: 20,
        min: 0,
        max: 20,
        change: function(event, ui) { 
            $('#header').text('debug=' + ui.value);
            options.hAxis.viewWindow.min = ui.value;
            drawChart();
        }
    });
});

function initChart() {
    chart = new google.visualization.SteppedAreaChart(document.getElementById('money'));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
        $('#slider').slider('enable');
    });
    drawChart();
}
function drawChart() {
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h3 id="header">Money</h3>
<div id="money"></div>
<div id="slider"></div>
</body>
</html>
```